# PostgreSQL Raise Notice Expression for Localization

Tags: postgresql, expression, plpgsql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Localized error message with parameters: %, %, %',  'a', 'b', 'c';
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The message block could be localized, but the order of parameters must always remain intact.

Is there a way to change the order of the percentage expression so that I would be able to localize the message portion without having to change the order of parameters?

Comment: I don't think the `RAISE` format can do that. But you can use the `format()` function, like: `RAISE NOTICE '%', format('%2$s message %1$s', param1, param2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `RAISE` format can do that.

But you can use the [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function, like:

```
RAISE NOTICE '%', format('%2$s message %1$s', param1, param2);
```